# can neighbors with cable internet access see each other's traffic?

Tags: networking, internet

I hear that cable Internet access uses a single shared link to connect a whole neighbourhood.  If I connect my computer directly to my cable modem and use a packet sniffer to inspect the traffic, would I see the all the packets being sent to my neighbours?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of.  [DOCSIS uses encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docsis#Security) to protect communication between your modem and the other end.  The 128-bit AES encryption used in BPI+ should be sufficiently safe for a good many years yet.

Comment: That's reassuring. Thanks for the answer, Daniel.